# Difference between del x and x=None for reclaiming the memory?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, del

I would like to reclaim memory of an instance variable in a class denoted by `self.x` below.

Should I use the command `del self.x`; or `self.x=None`? What would be their difference? Assuming that the command is to be put in a `__del__` or `__exit___` function of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that neither `del self.x` nor `self.x = None` frees any many memory. What they both do is decrease the reference counter of the object referenced  by `self.x` by one. Then if the counter of this object has reached 0 when the garbage collector will run then the memory will be freed

For the difference between the two, you will not be able to read the value `self.x` since `del self.x` will remove `x` from the instance dictionary. `self.x = None` is simply reassigning `self.x` the object None.